# Show symlink target in nautilus

Tags: 16.04, nautilus, symbolic-link, nautilus-script

Is it possible to show the target of a symbolic link in Nautilus as a column in the listing of a folder? Please don't point me to `ls -l`, I do know about it and use it, but it would be nice for UI users to have a UI way to see the link target in the listing.

Comment: I'm on my phone and cannot test but can you right click and select properties to see the linked item?

Answer (score 5):

This goal can be achieved via Nautilus Script.

Source of this answer is the answer's section of the question: [If I create a link to a folder, how can I get from that linked folder to the "real" folder from within Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187446/if-i-create-a-link-to-a-folder-how-can-i-get-from-that-linked-folder-to-the-re)

Also here is the origin of the script: [open-the-link-target-in-nautilus](https://www.gnome-look.org/content/show.php?content=134979). Listed dependencies are `perl` and `zenity`, but they are already installed by default.

There is no difference into the script content but in nowadays versions of Ubuntu the location path for Nautilus Scripts is changed to: `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts`

**1.** Create the script file and make it executable:

```
touch ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/"Open link target"
chmod +x ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/"Open link target"
```

**2.** Edit the script file:

```
gedit ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/"Open link target" &
```

**3.** Paste next lines as the script's content:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
#Title=Open-the-link-target-in-nautilus
#Title[fr]=ouvrir-le-repertoire-cible-dans-nautilus

#==============================================================================
#                     open-the-link-target-in-nautilus
#
#  author  : SLK
#  version : v2011051501
#  license : Distributed under the terms of GNU GPL version 2 or later
#
#==============================================================================
#
#  description :
#    nautilus-script : 
#    opens the target of a symbolic link of the selected object; if 
#    the target of the symbolic link is a file, opens the parent folder
#
#  informations :
#    - a script for use (only) with Nautilus. 
#    - to use, copy to your ${HOME}/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts/ directory.
#
#  WARNINGS :
#    - this script must be executable.
#    - package "zenity" must be installed
#
#==============================================================================

#==============================================================================
#                                                                     CONSTANTS

# 0 or 1  - 1: doesn't open but displays a message
DRY_RUN=0

#------>                                       some labels used for zenity [en]
z_title='Open the link target in nautilus'
z_err_bin_not_found='not found\nEXIT'
z_no_object='no object selected\nEXIT'
z_info_target='path of the target'
z_choice_open_nautilus='open target in nautilus'
z_choice_open_file='open file with default application'
z_choice_display_filepath='open a messagebox to copy filepath'

#------>                                       some labels used for zenity [fr]
#z_title='ouvrir le repertoire cible dans nautilus'
#z_err_bin_not_found='introuvable\nEXIT'
#z_no_object='aucun objet selectionne\nEXIT'
#z_info_target='chemin de la cible'
#z_choice_open_nautilus='ouvrir la cible dans nautilus'
#z_choice_open_file='ouvrir le fichier avec le programme par defaut'
#z_choice_display_filepath='ouvrir une boite de dialogue affichant le chemin du fichier'
#==============================================================================
#                                                                INIT VARIABLES

# may depends of your system
DIRNAME='/usr/bin/dirname'
GREP='/bin/grep'
NAUTILUS='/usr/bin/nautilus'
PERL='/usr/bin/perl'
READLINK='/bin/readlink'
XDG_OPEN='/usr/bin/xdg-open'
ZENITY='/usr/bin/zenity'

#==============================================================================
#                                                                     FUNCTIONS

function check_bin
{
    err=0
    for bin in $* ; do
        if [ ! -x "$bin" ] ; then
            $ZENITY --error --title "$z_title" \
              --text="$bin $z_err_bin_not_found"
            err=1
        fi
    done
    [ $err -eq 1 ] && exit 1
}
#==============================================================================
#                                                                          MAIN

# lets check for required binaries :
[ -x "$ZENITY" ] || {
    echo "[ERROR] $ZENITY not found : EXIT"
    exit 1
}
check_bin "$DIRNAME" "$GREP" "$NAUTILUS" "$PERL" "$READLINK"

# lets check if object is selected :
[ "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS" == "" ] && {
    $ZENITY --error --title "$z_title" \
      --text="$z_no_object"
    exit 1
}

# retrieve the first object selected :
first_object=`echo "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS" \
  | $PERL -ne 'print;exit'`

# lets check if local path :
[ `echo "$first_object" | $GREP -c "^/"` -eq 0 ] && {
    $ZENITY --error --title "$z_title" \
    --text="[ERROR] $first_object has not a valid path\nEXIT"
    exit 1
}

# retrieve the target path :
if [ -L "$first_object" ] ; then
    # symbolic link
    target=`$READLINK -f "$first_object"`
else
    # not a symbolic link :
    target="$first_object"
fi

if [ -d "$target" ] ; then
    # target is a directory
    target_to_open_in_nautilus="$target"
else
    # target is a file, let's take the parent directory
    target_to_open_in_nautilus=`$DIRNAME "$target"`
fi

### DRY RUN : noop

[ $DRY_RUN -eq 1 ] && {
    $ZENITY --info --title "$z_title" \
      --text="<b>DRY RUN</b>
first_object: $first_object
target: $target
target_to_open_in_nautilus: $target_to_open_in_nautilus"
    exit 0
}

### GO : let's open

choice=`$ZENITY --list --title="$z_title" --width="500" --height="200" \
  --text="<b>$z_info_target</b>\n$target" \
  --radiolist --column "" --column "action" \
  TRUE "$z_choice_open_nautilus" \
  FALSE "$z_choice_open_file" \
  FALSE "$z_choice_display_filepath"`

case $choice in
    "$z_choice_open_nautilus")
        $NAUTILUS --no-desktop "$target_to_open_in_nautilus"
    ;;
    "$z_choice_open_file")
        $XDG_OPEN "$target"
    ;;
    "$z_choice_display_filepath")
        $ZENITY --entry --title="$z_title" --width="500" \
          --text="$z_info_target" \
          --entry-text="$target" &
    ;;
    *)
        exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0

### EOF
```

**4.** Save the file, open Nautilus, 'right click' on some symlink, go to 'Scripts section' and click on 'Open link target':

[image]

**5.** Then will be appeared this dialogue box:

[image]

---

I'm afraid that, if you want to add a new column into the list view, the source code of Nautilus must be changed and recompiled.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 22.04, GNOME nautilus 42.2. Used Kevin Kane's patch to highlight target file too. Since I open the target 90% of time and copy the filepath 10% of time, I'm considering splitting the full script with menu box into 2 or 3 different scripts so I can skip the menu box. Opening link in new tab instead of new window, or even in same tab, would be a nice option too, but I don't know about an option with the command line. Opening in same tab may be too low-level.

Comment: Hello @hsandt. Thank you letting us (the community) know, this approach still work. Unfortunately, right now, I don't have a time to implement the features you've mentioned, but I believe you can do it on your self by the help of the anvwers given under this question: https://askubuntu.com/q/55656/566421

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by pa4080 worked well for me on Ubuntu 16.04. However, for links to files I found it is more helpful if the new Nautilus window  opens with the target file selected. This is similar to when doing a find within Nautilus, if one right clicks on one of the search results and chooses Open Item Location.

To achieve this, I replaced the following section

```
if [ -d "$target" ] ; then
    # target is a directory
    target_to_open_in_nautilus="$target"
else
    # target is a file, let's take the parent directory
    target_to_open_in_nautilus=`$DIRNAME "$target"`
fi
```

with

```
target_to_open_in_nautilus="$target"
```

Now the new Nautilus window will open with the link's target selected when it is a file.